# Dynamical add form elements, store them to MySQL and change/delete them in future

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, dynamic

I found this solution for my problem but I need some additional help:

[How to use jQuery to add form elements dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744594/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-form-elements-dynamically)

I have a form (here I'll copy a short version), and it is used for entering some tasks by users. Users can enter as many tasks as they like in period of 2 years. **The script is working correctly**, but I have a problem with counter of element IDs. Probably it can be solved with slight modification of javascript.

So here is html:

```
<div class="extraNew">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Task:</label>
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Task" type="text" name="task"></textarea>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Description" type="text" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" id="addRow" class="addRow">Add row</p></a>
</div>
```

And here is javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('<div/>', {
         'class' : 'extra', html: GetHtml()
     }).appendTo('#container');
     $('#addRow').click(function () {
           $('<div/>', {
               'class' : 'extra', html: GetHtml()
     }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

     });
 });
 function GetHtml()
{
      var len = $('.extra').length;
    var $html = $('.extraNew').clone();
    $html.find('[name=task]')[0].name="task" + len;
    $html.find('[name=description]')[0].name="description" + len;
    return $html.html();    
}
});//]]>
</script>
```

But POST results I get afterwards are not so good:

```
Array (
    [task] => blah
    [description] => blah
    [task0] => blah
    [description0] => blah
    [task1] => blah
    [description1] => blah ... )
```

And If I fill this form only once, without adding new row I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [task] => blah
    [description] => blah
    [task0] => 
    [description0] => 
)
```

This ZERO bothers me. It always resets the counter to 0, and I'm afraid of unwanted problems when users will want to change something in the future. I need to give users an option to change or delete some task. I'm afraid that these actions will make a mess in MySQL.

I would like to add ID 1 (or zero) to the first set of form elements, and set counter from last set of elements (so if only 1 set is entered, the next set will have ID 2 ofcourse). And afterwards I will collect all POST data and store it in MySQL with FOR loop without worrying of ID order.

And with the same method I will output the data via PHP. So probably, I will first create initial form with PHP and query from MySQL - If some rows already exists in MySQL, display them and set counter incrementally; and if returns 0 rows, display elements starting from 1 (or zero).

I hope I explained everything correctly. So to repeat the question: How to change jquery to create element IDs incrementally and always making sure that new element ID is +1 from last element ID?

Comment: can someone please help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120124/insert-dynamic-select-box-value-in-mysql-database-and-show-data-submitted-messag/44123272#44123272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your inputs like `tasks[task][0]` and `task[description][0]` so your initial markup would be:

```
<div class="extraNew">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Task:</label>
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Task" type="text" name="tasks[task][0]"></textarea>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Description" type="text" name="tasks[description][0]"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" id="addRow" class="addRow">Add row</p></a>
</div>
```

then when you add a new pair to the dom you should do something like:

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    var extraHTML = '<div class="extraNew">\
    <div class="row">\
        <label>Task:</label>\
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Task" type="text" name="tasks[task][EXTRAINDEX]"></textarea>\
        <label>Description:</label>\
        <textarea class="span3" placeholder="Description" type="text" name="tasks[description][EXTRAINDEX]"></textarea>\
    </div>\
</div>';
var count = $('.extraNew').length;
extraHTML = extraHTML.replace(/EXTRAINDEX/g, count);
$(extraHTML).appendTo('#container').hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

Then in the post you'll get a nice array of the form:

```
Array( 
     [0] => Array( 
              [task] => "whatever", 
              [description] => "whatevermore"
            ), 
     [1] => Array( 
              [task] => "whatever1", 
              [description] => "whatevermore1"
            )
)
```

Comment: Thnx for reply, but there is something wrong...

I can't add new row (nothing happens) and my POST results are different:

    Array
    (
        [tasks] => Array
            (
                [task] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => some text
                    )
    
                [description] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => some text
                    )
    
            )
    )

Comment: Ups, sorry. I've added script in head instead of body. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make array of name like  `name="task[]".` it will help to post all values.

And your javascript portion is not clear to me.What exactly is your problem?

You can use hidden filed for tracking ID's.Every time you add an item,increment it by one.
Or second option is assign a class to your field. and get size of class.I think your are asking this.