# Add Multiple textbox by add butoon click in .net

Tags: c#-4.0

I Want to Create a Multiple textbox on add button click three textbox and a droplist should be added on every click and on save button the the value should be saved in database

Comment: Share your code. Did you try something ?

Comment: Website, desktop, ...?

Comment: in web application

Comment: ya i tried using jquery

Comment: bt while updating the value i  m not able to update new value

Comment: www.fingrofinserve.com/app

Comment: this is the link and user id is admin and password is admin@123

Comment: try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744594/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-form-elements-dynamically